# Grabbing text from select tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, select

I'm trying to change the second select statement by what is selected in the first.

This is the code that I have currently, and it's not working:

```
function getSchedText() {

    var schedGrab = $("#schedGrab").text();
    if (schedGrab == "English") {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/english.html');
    }
    else if (schedGrab == "Spanish") {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/spanish.html');
    }
    else if (schedGrab == "") {
        $("#schedPost").load();
    }
    else {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/testdoc.html');
    }
}
```

This is the according HTML:

`<select name="class1" class="login" id="schedGrab" onclick="getSchedText()">php include</select>`

`<select name="class2" class="login" id="schedPost"></select>`

Comment: use `.change()` event to grab the value of the select box. http://api.jquery.com/change/ and i think you want to dynamic select box, Please visit the link to achieve that http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/03/04/dynamic-select-box-with-php-and-jquery.html

Comment: How do you invoke `getSchedText` ? . Is there a change event handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like below

```
$('#schedGrab').change(function() {
    var schedGrab = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if (schedGrab == "English") {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/english.html');
    }
    else if (schedGrab == "Spanish") {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/spanish.html');
    }
    else if (schedGrab == "") {
        $("#schedPost").load();
    }
    else {
        $("#schedPost").load('../start/testdoc.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: works for me, have you removed the function from onclick and put above snippet in $(document).ready(function() { ... }) ?

Comment: Ah, had a misplaced semicolon, go figure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you were putting the title using "JQuery"

try with this way

```
$("#schedGrab").change(function(){
     //Embed your ifelse here but strongly suggest to go for switch statement

     alert($(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected option text

```
var schedGrab = $("#schedGrab option:selected").text();
```